# where do i need to add my custom javascript (which will be rendering the results inside the modern web part) inside my client-side web part project

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have built my first client side web part as mentioned on this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part. now the web part will show a simple hello word.

But i have the following JavaScript :-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="123123">123</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var idfromurl = window.location.href;// do extra steps to get the item id....
$(function () { 
        
    var url = "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Dept')/items?$filter=ID eq idfromurl&$select=ID,Title,desc&$orderby= Title asc";
    var html="";
    $.ajax({
     url: url,
     method: "GET",   
     headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
     success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){
        
            var items=data.d.results;
            for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){

                html+= items[i].Title + "|"+ items[i].desc+"<br/>";
                                    
                
            }
            $("#123123").after(html);
        }
     },
     error: function (data) {       
     }
    });
});

</script>
```

which will get a parameter from a url, and send an api call to get an item description and item title, and should then render the result inside the web part.

but i am not sure where inside my web part project i can add this javascript code? should it be inside the `.ts` file under the  `public render(): void` method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can render the list item using REST API using this.context.spHttpClient.get() method in the public render():void method in .ts file.

The following article for your reference.

[Retrieve SharePoint List Items Using SharePoint Framework Development Model](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-sharepoint-framework-development-model/)

Code Example about SharePoint CRUD for list item from github.

[sp-dev-fx-webparts/samples/sharepoint-crud](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/sharepoint-crud)